# Running windows shell commands with python

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, shell

How can we interact with OS shell using Python ?
I want to run windows cmd commands via python. How can it be achieved ?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to use python as a shell replacement?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/182077)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The newer `subprocess.check_output` and similar commands are supposed to replace `os.system`.  See [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for details.  While I can't test this on Windows (because I don't have access to any Windows machines), the following should work:

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output("dir C:", shell=True)
```

`check_output` returns a string of the output from your command.  Alternatively, `subprocess.call` just runs the command and returns the status of the command (usually 0 if everything is okay).

Also note that, in python 3, that string output is now `bytes` output.  If you want to change this into a string, you need something like

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output("dir C:", shell=True).decode()
```

If necessary, [you can tell it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) the kind of encoding your program outputs.  The default is `utf-8`, which typically works fine, but other standard options are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Also note that @bluescorpion says in the comments that Windows 10 needs a trailing backslash, as in `check_output("dir C:\\", shell=True)`.  The double backslash is needed because `\` is a special character in python, so it has to be [escaped](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-22).  (Also note that even prefixing the string with `r` doesn't help if `\` is the very last character of the string — `r"dir C:\"` is a syntax error, though `r"dir C:\ "` is not.)

Comment: This works in Windows 7.  Thanks.  It does return \r\n at the end of the string, so you might need to strip that out with a `[0:-2]` substring.

Comment: Using `[0:-2]` for that purpose makes me nervous.  If anyone takes that code to apply it in a non-Windows context, they'll certainly change the obvious `dir C:` to `ls` or whatever.  But they could easily fail to realize that `[0:-2]` should be changed to `[0:-1]`.  I'd recommend [`.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) instead, which would work on any platform (unless you want to capture other trailing whitespace), and also makes the reason behind the string alteration clearer.

Comment: @Mikw: I have a windows  command which is used for deployment.Just a single line of command. How can I call it from an external python3.4 script

Comment: Just use the code above, but replace `dir C:` with whatever your single line of code is.

Comment: I don't have access to any windows machines, but I'm guessing you're using python 3.  If so, you might want to look into [the `universal_newlines` argument](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Comment: Works in Win 10 with a slight modification: 
check_output("dir C:\\", shell=True)

Comment: Using shlex.split() can be useful when determining the correct tokenization for args, especially in complex cases.  It also helps in escaping the backslashes for Windows use.  See the note in the Python documentation. 
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: Can this module be used in unix based systems ?

Comment: @codingbruh Yes.  In fact (as I noted in a previous comment), I don't even have access to any windows machines.  I use it routinely on macOS and various species of linux without any trouble.  You just need to give it commands that the shell will understand — e.g., `ls /` instead of `dir C:`.

Answer (score 20):

You would use the os module [system method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system).

You just put in the string form of the command, the return value is the windows enrivonment variable COMSPEC

For example:

os.system('python') opens up the windows command prompt and runs the python interpreter

[image: os.system('python') example]

Comment: Sidetip: Use `alt+prtscr` to just get a screenshot of the active window. ;)

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Although documentation recommends using [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.system), I find this more pythonic for simple tasks.

Answer (score 19):

Refactoring of @srini-beerge's answer which gets the output and the return code

```
import subprocess
def run_win_cmd(cmd):
    result = []
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                               shell=True,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in process.stdout:
        result.append(line)
    errcode = process.returncode
    for line in result:
        print(line)
    if errcode is not None:
        raise Exception('cmd %s failed, see above for details', cmd)
```

Answer (score 11):

Simple Import os package and run below command.

```
import os
os.system("python test.py")
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `subprocess` package with the code as below:

```
import subprocess
cmdCommand = "python test.py"   #specify your cmd command
process = subprocess.Popen(cmdCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
print output
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
result = []
win_cmd = 'ipconfig'(curr_user,filename,ip_address)
process = subprocess.Popen(win_cmd,
shell=True,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
for line in process.stdout:
    print line
result.append(line)
errcode = process.returncode
for line in result:
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, although you don't need to use `import subprocess` just in case you need to work with adb.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
# import subprocess

root = Tk()
root.title("Shutdown PC")
root.geometry("500x500")

def button():
   os.system('timeout /T 10 /nobreak')
   os.system('SHUTDOWN/s')
   
   

b = Button(root, text="SHUTDOWN PC", width=30, height=2, command = button)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```