# cannot open files in beyond compare using python

Tags: python, beyondcompare3

I am making use of Beyond Compare 3 to see the difference between two XML files. I am willing to make a small python script which on executing will open files ready to compare in Beyond Compare tool.

So far I tried invoking BC3 from command line syntax as below and it works:

```
BCompare.exe "c:\Ref-2.xml"  "c:\Cop-2.xml"
```

but when I try to execute same syntax from python script as shown below, It throws error

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output('BCompare.exe "c:\Ref-2.xml"  "c:\Cop-2.xml"', shell=True)
```

The error which is shown is:

```
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'BCompare.exe "c:\Ref-2.xml"  "c:\Cop-2.xml"' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

am I missing something? I tried different solutions to open command line instructions using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python) tutorial and many others but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this. Give Absolute path of .exe

```
check_output(absolute_path_of_beyond_compare "c:\Ref-2.xml"  "c:\Cop-2.xml"', shell=True)
```

I am able to open the Beyond Compare using following code:

```
from subprocess import check_output

check_output("BCompare.exe Test1.txt Test2.txt", shell=True)
```

where BCompare.exe path is added in path variable and Test1.txt Test2.txt are present in the same directory from where i have executed the program.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it produces same error. I gave absolute path of `BCompare.exe`

Comment: however, with `subprocess.call('"C:\Users\BHD4ABT\Desktop\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe')` i am able to open beyond compare tool but cannot add files to compare

Comment: I modified above answer. Check That please.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe", r"FullFilePath_File1", r"FullFilePath_File2"])
```

I tested on mine, and it works.
Instead of checkout, I am using Popen.
I am using Jupyter notebook by installing `Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64`

Python version = `3.6.5`

Answer (score 0):

use exact path where the beyond compare is installed or add that to your environment variable "Path".
in case using exact path of installation put something line "\"C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe\" test1.txt test2.txt"
the \" enables to read the special characters and extra spaces in path