# Python check for Completed and failed Task Windows scheduler

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

Does anyone know of a way or a resource I can look at to be able to check the status of all my Windows tasks I have in the task scheduler? I would like to see if that see if the task failed or was successful. I would like to do this in Python.

I have looked a little at using the win32com.client module. I can see what tasks are but can't find what the status of completed job are.

```
import win32com.client
scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch("Schedule.Service")
scheduler.Connect()
tasks = scheduler.GetRunningTasks(1)
names = [tasks.Item(i+1).Name for i in range(tasks.Count)]
print names
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following uses the [Task Scheduler API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383600) to print basic information for all registered tasks, including the last run time and result.

```
import win32com.client

TASK_ENUM_HIDDEN = 1
TASK_STATE = {0: 'Unknown',
              1: 'Disabled',
              2: 'Queued',
              3: 'Ready',
              4: 'Running'}

scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
scheduler.Connect()

n = 0
folders = [scheduler.GetFolder('\\')]
while folders:
    folder = folders.pop(0)
    folders += list(folder.GetFolders(0))
    tasks = list(folder.GetTasks(TASK_ENUM_HIDDEN))
    n += len(tasks)
    for task in tasks:
        settings = task.Definition.Settings
        print('Path       : %s' % task.Path)
        print('Hidden     : %s' % settings.Hidden)
        print('State      : %s' % TASK_STATE[task.State])
        print('Last Run   : %s' % task.LastRunTime)
        print('Last Result: %s\n' % task.LastTaskResult)
print('Listed %d tasks.' % n)
```

This starts with only the root folder in the list. Each pass through the loop pops a folder; pushes all of its subfolders; and lists the tasks in the folder. It continues until the list of folders is empty.

**COM Interfaces**

- [`ITaskService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381832)
- [`ITaskFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381330)
- [`IRegisteredTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380751)
- [`ITaskDefinition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381313)
- [`ITaskSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381843)

Alternatively, here's a `walk_tasks` generator that's modeled on the standard library's `os.walk`.

```
import os
import pywintypes
import win32com.client

TASK_ENUM_HIDDEN = 1
TASK_STATE = {
    0: 'Unknown',
    1: 'Disabled',
    2: 'Queued',
    3: 'Ready',
    4: 'Running'
}

def walk_tasks(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, include_hidden=True,
               serverName=None, user=None, domain=None, password=None):
    scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
    scheduler.Connect(serverName, user, domain, password)
    if isinstance(top, bytes):
        if hasattr(os, 'fsdecode'):
            top = os.fsdecode(top)
        else:
            top = top.decode('mbcs')
    if u'/' in top:
        top = top.replace(u'/', u'\\')
    include_hidden = TASK_ENUM_HIDDEN if include_hidden else 0
    try:
        top = scheduler.GetFolder(top)
    except pywintypes.com_error:
        if onerror is not None:
            onerror(error)
        return
    for entry in _walk_tasks_internal(top, topdown, onerror, include_hidden):
        yield entry


def _walk_tasks_internal(top, topdown, onerror, flags):
    try:
        folders = list(top.GetFolders(0))
        tasks = list(top.GetTasks(flags))
    except pywintypes.com_error as error:
        if onerror is not None:
            onerror(error)
        return

    if not topdown:
        for d in folders:
            for entry in _walk_tasks_internal(d, topdown, onerror, flags):
                yield entry

    yield top, folders, tasks

    if topdown:
        for d in folders:
            for entry in _walk_tasks_internal(d, topdown, onerror, flags):
                yield entry
```

**Example**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 0
    for folder, subfolders, tasks in walk_tasks('/'):
        n += len(tasks)
        for task in tasks:
            settings = task.Definition.Settings
            print('Path       : %s' % task.Path)
            print('Hidden     : %s' % settings.Hidden)
            print('State      : %s' % TASK_STATE[task.State])
            print('Last Run   : %s' % task.LastRunTime)
            print('Last Result: %s\n' % task.LastTaskResult)
    print('Listed %d tasks.' % n)
```

Answer (score 1):

task scheduler can be accessed from command line using  `schtasks` and `at`

*schtasks*: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

*at*: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755618%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

run `schtasks /query` from python using `subprocess.check_output` see
[Running windows shell commands with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722006.aspx

The `tasklist` command lists all running programs and services or in powershell `get-process`

https://superuser.com/questions/914782/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows

Comment: I am looking to check for staus of stuff that failed or completed. Not just what is running