# List Windows scheduled tasks with Python

Tags: python, windows, taskscheduler

I am trying to list all scheduled tasks on Windows with a Python script.

On this post, [Python check for Completed and failed Task Windows scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634214/python-check-for-completed-and-failed-task-windows-schedluer)
there is some code which worked.

```
import win32com.client

TASK_STATE = {0: 'Unknown',
              1: 'Disabled',
              2: 'Queued',
              3: 'Ready',
              4: 'Running'}

scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
scheduler.Connect()

folders = [scheduler.GetFolder('\\')]
while folders:
    folder = folders.pop(0)
    folders += list(folder.GetFolders(0))
    for task in folder.GetTasks(0):
        print('Path       : %s' % task.Path)
        print('State      : %s' % TASK_STATE[task.State])
        print('Last Run   : %s' % task.LastRunTime)
        print('Last Result: %s\n' % task.LastTaskResult)
```

However, I would like to display the path of the file it executes (e.g. `c:\test\aaa.bat`) and the parameters of the command. How could this be done?

And could anyone explain the meaning of some commands in the code:

1. [] in the code "[scheduler.GetFolder('\')]"
2. Where could I get the detail explaination of code like list(folder.GetFolders(0)), folder.GetTasks(0)? Is there any documentation available?

Comment: Use the provided links. `Dispatch` returns an `ITaskService` instance. `GetFolder('\\')` returns an `ITaskFolder` for the root folder in the scheduler namespace. `GetFolders(0)` returns the subfolders in an `ITaskFolderCollection`. `GetTasks(0)` gets the non-hidden tasks in the folder in an `IRegisteredTaskCollection`. To include hidden tasks, use `GetTasks(TASK_ENUM_HIDDEN)`, i.e. `GetTasks(1)`. Enumerating this returns the task as an `IRegisteredTask`. Note that its `Definition` property is an [`ITaskDefinition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381313).

Comment: @eryksun Thanks! I noticed you are also the author of the code of the link, it really helps! '[]' usually is used for list, what is the purpose here?

Comment: There's nothing special. It's just traversing the task tree using a list and a loop. It starts with the root folder in the list. The loop pops a folder; pushes all of its subfolders; and lists the tasks in the folder. It continues until the list is empty. It could be generalized into an `os.walk`  style generator function that yields the path, subfolders and tasks in each folder.

Comment: I added a `walk_tasks` generator function to my answer on the linked question.