# get 'last run time' from task scheduler, python

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to find the last run time of a specific task in Windows Task Scheduler on Windows 10.

At the beginning I used `schtasks /QUERY /FO LIST /V /TN "TASK_NAME"`, which gave me a string that I converted to datetime. But, then I realized that I have a problem with different formats.

Is there a way to get this data as a date time from the beginning or at least as a string of Unix time?

Comment: Can you show an example of the output that gave you trouble?

Comment: The `/xml` option gives times in ISO format.

Comment: 1. Where should I write "/xml"?

2. in order to convert from string do datetime I used Last_Run_Time = datetime.strptime(Last_Run_Time, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
but if the format changes to  '%m-%d-%Y or  '%d/%m/%Y and etc. then I'm having a problem.

Comment: I tried the command 'schtasks /QUERY /XML /TN "TASK_NAME"' but it doesn't give me the attribute(?) of last run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383600): **Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces**.

For example in Python: 
[Python check for Completed and failed Task Windows scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634214/python-check-for-completed-and-failed-task-windows-scheduler)