# Create a new folder in Windows Task Scheduler with win32com

Tags: python, win32com, windows-task-scheduler

I can't find a way to create a new folder with win32com in the Windows Task Scheduler, i can only open an already created one such has

```
import win32com.client as win32
service = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Schedule.Service')
service.Connect()
root_folder = service.GetFolder("\\")
```

is there way to create a new one without going into the scheduler itself?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to cast it to  `ITaskFolder` first an then acess the `CreateFolder` method

```
import win32com.client as win32

service = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Schedule.Service')
service.Connect()
root_folder = service.GetFolder("\\")
f = win32.CastTo(root_folder, "ITaskFolder")
f.CreateFolder('test_name')
```

Comment: Do you think you need the cast? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itaskservice-getfolder suggests that `ITaskService::GetFolder()` already returns a  `ITaskFolder` interface. I haven’t tested this to be fair.

Comment: @DS_London I think the way you open the service will dictate if you need to cast it or not, with `win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Schedule.Service')`  the `GetFolder` method is not available

Comment: On my system at least (Windows 11), `EnsureDispatch('Schedule.Service')` returns an object of type: `<class 'win32com.gen_py.E34CB9F1-C7F7-424C-BE29-027DCC09363Ax0x1x0.ITaskService.ITaskService'>`.  The gen_py file `ITaskService.py` includes a `GetFolder()` method, which returns a Dispatch interface with Clsid `{8CFAC062-A080-4C15-9A88-AA7C2AF80DFC}`, which is the IID for `ITaskFolder`, and `ITaskFolder.py` contains the `CreateFolder()` method. Or put more succinctly, your code , on my machine at least, runs fine and creates a new folder without the `CastTo`.

Comment: To follow on ... where you DO need CastTo is when you work with the Tasks themselves, as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963769/how-to-access-windows-scheduler-actions-with-python-and-win32com/70971108#70971108