# How Can I Write a Python Script to launch different applications in my computer.(e.g: opening command Prompt,opening My computer etc)

Tags: python, cmd, scripting, automation

Suppose I want to launch command prompt and write different command there.
How Can I do this by simply running one python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this previous answer.
[Running windows shell commands with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python) I believe it has what you are looking for.

Comment: when running the following command :
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> check_output("dir C :", shell =True).decode()
 I am getting errors like :

File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout