# Use python to run multiple commands inside the wine cmd?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, wine

Using python I can get either of these to work:

```
subprocess.call(['wine', 'cmd'])
os.system("wine cmd")
```

I'm using Ubuntu and python 3.5, Once I get into the wine cmd prompt I can no longer run commands, non of the ways to run multiple commands that I have seen online work, they don't error out, it just opens the cmd and pauses, I think it treats the cmd once open as a running command and is waiting to move on to the next command which it assumes is for the shell not the wine cmd, how can i then run commands inside the wine cmd once opened?

**edit:** Basically any time I run a command that requires further user input from within that command, how do I interact inside of that command?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: If you want to control a wine program remotely and add some input to it, use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com).

Answer (score 0):

You could build up from DOS through BASH to python as in the example code here. I cut and paste the code into python 2.7 and it worked, but you might like to confirm on 3.5

If you specifically need interaction rather than just running a DOS command then you could use subprocess.Popen.communicate to interact with your script which then interacts with wine/dos.

```
import subprocess, os, stat
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import PIPE
from subprocess import check_output
command_script="/tmp/temp_script.sh"
f1 = open(command_script,'w')
f1.write("#!/bin/bash\n")
#to run a dos command
#f1.write(r'WINEPREFIX=/path/tp/wine/prefix wine cmd /c @mydoscommand argval1'+'\n')
#for example
f1.write(r'wine cmd /c @echo Hello_world'+'\n')
#or to run a specifically pathed executable
#f1.write(r'WINEPREFIX=/path/tp/wine/prefix wine "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\path\\to\\executable.exe" additionalargs '+'\n')
f1.close()
st = os.stat(command_script)
os.chmod(command_script, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
p = Popen(command_script, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
rc = p.returncode
print output
os.remove(command_script)
```

Have a look at the answers where I nicked some of the code from [Running windows shell commands with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python) and [calling-an-external-command-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)