# Changing the shell's directory with python script

Tags: python, cmd

What can I put in a python script that will change the shell directory when I run it. For example when I run:

```
c:\users\myname> python myscript.py
```

After the script run I get the prompt, for example:

```
c:\users\myname\desktop>
```

Comment: Nothing :(  Python will be run in a subshell and cannot affect the state of the calling shell.

Comment: Is it possible at least to kill the shell that I called the script from? This way I would open another shell and kill the previous one.

Comment: Could you explain more about what you are trying to use this for?

Comment: The Python script needs to start a new shell process after it changes the directory. Use the `subprocess` library to do this.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python) what you're referring to? You can run shell command to cd into the directory you want?

Comment: This is my ideia: made a script to manage my study. There is a lot of ebooks  I what to study. Each ebook have its directory. If there's a new book I want to study I just:

Comment: This is my ideia: made a script to manage my study. There is a lot of ebooks  I what to study. Each ebook have its directory. If there's a new book I want to study I just: `cd book_dir` then I run `study.py --manage book.pdf`. This adds the book to a database and keeps track of the file directory. When I don't know what I want to study I just run: `study.py` and the script opens one of the books in its database. But I also want it to put the command line in the book directory. I'm on windows 7 using python 3.5