# How to call command prompt functions?

Tags: python, command-prompt

The python documentation for this is very dry, I was wondering if you guys could help me.

My goal is to make python execute commands that I would normally execute in the command prompt. (I'm running windows)

If I run

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe")
```

It opens the command prompt. Is there a way to get the program to write in something like "dir C"?

Comment: There's a library in the Standard Library for that: [subprocess.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running windows shell commands with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os library:

```
import os
os.system('dir C')
```

If you want to open a new command prompt and run a command in it, then I can't help you there. I tried to figure that out for macOS a while ago to no avail.