# Python Execute Error

Tags: python, powershell

```
import subprocess
command = r'C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c ". \"C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware View\Server\extras\PowerShell\add-snapin.ps1\""'
subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
```

I use to this code but i recived error on powershell

```
add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5.
At C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware View\Server\extras\PowerShell\add-snapin.ps1:25 char:2
```

Comment: try run this " Get-Module -Name VMware* -ListAvailable | Import-Module "

Comment: or this " C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware View\Server\Extras\PowerShell\add-snapin.ps1 "

Comment: You, might get your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try with this:-

```
import os

command = r'C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c ". \"C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware View\Server\extras\PowerShell\add-snapin.ps1\""'
os.system(command)
#or
os.system(command,shell=True)
```

Comment: check the power shell commend. The problem is with your power shell command not with python code. First manually execute the power shell and check whether work or not.