# How do I input data into a command prompt from within python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, operating-system

I want to open a cmd and then input data into the command line from python. I plan to call PEST calibration software to open from within python and I want to start by opening a cmd.

I am using Python 2.7 and so subprocess doesn't seem to work.  I have tried os.system('cmd') and I can open the prompt but I can't input any data.

```
import os
os.system('cmd')
```

Comment: what was your subprocess code?

Comment: I tried the following:                                                             
    subprocess.call("cmd" + "pest", shell=True)
    subprocess.Popen('cmd')
    subprocess.run('cmd')

Comment: What is the command to run PEST calibration software, and what happens when you run the PEST command

Comment: Used to work for me on Linux, as far as I can remember, but since you're on Windows, I believe what you are looking for has been answered in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python).

Comment: To run PEST from the cmd, I type: pest forward.pst    , where pest is the name of the application and forward.pst is a text file that pest needs to open and read to run.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the exact resulting string to os.system(). Ex:

```
os.system('notepad.exe')
```

In other words, os.system behaves the same way a console would.

Comment: I tried inputting the call I use to launch PEST in the cmd into os.system()      
    os.system('pest forward.pst')                                                                                        But a prompt didn't open.  It looked like a prompt may have opened but then closed so quickly I couldn't even see it.