# Python run command with arguments in Windows CMD

Tags: python, cmd

Good day!

I need to run this command as a whole in windows CMD:

```
>abx.exe -s -t file.txt db usr pwd
```

tryed

```
os.run('abx.exe -s -t file.txt db usr pwd')
```

and

```
gc = ['abx.exe', '-s', '-t', 'file.txt', 'db', 'usr', 'pwd']
pr = subprocess.Popen(gc)
pr.wait()
```

but both did't work. It is not executing anything.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python). You can try: `check_output("abx.exe -s -t file.txt db usr pwd", shell=True)`

Comment: the absolute path to `abx.exe` executable might be required

Comment: the python file is in the same directory

Comment: Do you run the python script from this folder ?

Comment: @jigga what is the error you're getting? does my answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
import os
os.system("your command")
```