# How to run external program with parameters from Python

Tags: python, cmd

generally in PowerShell I running command:

```
cd C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\File Namee\
```

then I am executing program with specific parameters:

```
.\program.exe /F:aa.dvl /PPP_ZZZ
```

and it works, now my question, how to execute it by python script ? I tried subprocess and os.system but it doesn't work for me.

```py
file = ['C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\File Namee\\', '.program.exe/F:aa.dvl /PPP_ZZZ']
subprocess.call(file)
```

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43581356/3091398).

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
file = ['C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\File Namee\\program.exe', '/F:aa.dvl' '/PPP_ZZZ']
subprocess.call(file)
```

so each parameter as a separate list element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `os.system("/path/to/exe/File.exe -parameters params")`

Comment: That was working for me: ```os.system(" C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\File Namee\\program.exe /F:C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop\\File Namee\\aa.dvl /PPP_ZZZ") ```