# Is there a way to update Windows via python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I'm currently working on creating a python 3.7 script that will test if some computers are running at least Windows 10 v.1803 and update them if necessary. I already have the part that checks for the version, but I don't know how - if it's even possible in the first place - to actually preform the update.

If it's not possible through python, how can I do it through something such as VBScript and call it from python?

Comment: If you know the appropriate command, you can just issue a system call to execute that command. Executing a system command is a duplicate here; which command to execute is off-topic here. Try Super User. See for example https://superuser.com/questions/462425/can-i-get-more-information-on-what-windows-update-is-doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running windows shell commands with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python)