# Putting a code from a .bat file into a Dag file apache airflow

Tags: airflow, scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I' am new in BI and I need some help I'am using windows Jobscheduler in order to executer tasks , but sometimes it bugs so i am moving to apache airflow , I have already a bat file who execute but I want to use it in apache airflow dags , this is my file bat code

cd /d D:\EXMOOV\Scripts

call RunDTS.bat EXMOOV Js_002_MOOV_AIR

I want to put it in a dag file code  in order to execute it , so I took an example of a Dag code and try it to put it so the file become unreadable and apache airflow didin't read it , this is my try :

```
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


default_args = {
    'owner': 'Brahim',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),

}
dag = DAG(
    'My_first_test_code',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)


t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag,
)

cd /d D:\EXMOOV\Scripts


call RunDTS.bat EXMOOV Js_002_MOOV_AIR


    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='sleep',
        depends_on_past=False,
        bash_command='sleep 5',
        retries=3,
        dag=dag,
    )
    dag.doc_md = __doc__

t1.doc_md = """\

templated_command = """
{% for i in range(5) %}
    echo "{{ ds }}"
    echo "{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7)}}"
    echo "{{ params.my_param }}"
{% endfor %}
"""

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='templated',
    depends_on_past=False,
    bash_command=templated_command,
    params={'my_param': 'Parameter I passed in'},
    dag=dag,
)

t1 >> [t2, t3]
```

I just want those a dag file who read those two lines  that's all in order to execute the script the file in format .bat used to execute etl jobs in ibm datastage  .

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned your architecture. Yet it seems like your Airflow is on Linux machines or it is installed on Windows Subsystem for Linux. Either way I think you can use Python library for Windows Remote Management (pywinrm) which should allow you to access the resources on windows server. Besides, your syntax to run windows command on python script is not correct. Check this out.!
[Running windows shell commands with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python)