# Python Chromedriver End Task Annoying Flicker

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

I am building a Tkinter app with python that initializes multiple selenium webdrivers. The initial problem was that lots of chromedriver.exe instances were filling up user's memory, even after using `driver.quit()` (sometimes). So to get rid of this issue, when closing the tkinter app, I wrote this line `os.system("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe /T")`, that solves my problem, but, by using this, a command prompt instance is initiated that self kills almost instantly. The problem is that the user can see it and I find it kinda disturbing. Is there any way I could hide it? Or is there a workaround for my initial problem, that is user friendly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running windows shell commands with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894993/running-windows-shell-commands-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use both driver.close() and driver.quit() in your code in order to free memory.

```
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the memory footprint you should use ChromeDriver-Service:

First you start the service, then use it when creating new drivers, and finally stop the service before program exit.

Put the code below in chrome_factory.py and then:

- on program start call chrome_factory.start_service()
- to create new driver call chrome_factory.create_driver()
- the service and drivers will be automatically stopped/quit at program exit.

Using this approach will result in only ever having single chromedriver.exe process.

```
# chrome_factory.py
import atexit
from os.path import expanduser
from typing import Optional

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

EXECUTABLE = expanduser("~/bin/chromedriver")

_chrome_service: Optional[Service] = None


def start_service():
    global _chrome_service
    _chrome_service = Service(EXECUTABLE)
    _chrome_service.start()
    atexit.register(_chrome_service.stop)


def create_driver() -> webdriver.Remote:
    global _chrome_service

    opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opts.add_argument("--headless")

    driver = webdriver.Remote(_chrome_service.service_url,
                              desired_capabilities=opts.to_capabilities())

    atexit.register(driver.quit)
    return driver


def main():
    start_service()
    for _ in range(20):
        create_driver()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is really helpful. But that single chromedriver.exe process still remains in task manager memory, right? If so, how can I get rid of that too? I am asking this because I am facing an issue with `ChromeDriverManager().install()`, that raises `PermissionError`, meaning all chromedriver processes  need to be killed.